# Entity-relationship for database design

Tags: database-design, erd

[image]

Customers have the option to not provide a review or leave as many reviews as they want, but they cant have multiple reviews for the same product.  How do I model this?

Comment: @bbaird sorry so basically my data that im working with customers have the option to not provide a review or leave as many reviews as they want. But, they cant have like multiple reviews for the same product

Comment: It's just saying that every review must have a customer and a product, not that every Customer or Product must have a review. (The image is a bit blurred for me, and the multiplicity on the Review end of the Product-Review relation looks likes it might not include 0; I would count that a design error.)

Comment: @James - Yep. Otherwise you could have a non-customer writing reviews about non-existing products. Trolls would love that!

Comment: Add a unique key on review (productID, customerID).  Add a pre-insert trigger on the review table, that prevents inserting reviews if the customer hasn't bought the product.

Comment: Not all constraints can be represented in an ERD.  I believe an ERD can show a unique constraint.  The unique constraint would prevent duplicate reviews, ie. the same customer reviewing the same product multiple times.  Also, that unique key could be the primary key, it would allow you to drop "reviewID".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I begin, let's address a few issues with your current data model:

1. This is not a relational data model.  You have no keys.  You have defined pointers between tables and nothing more.
2. Because this is not a relational model, implementing certain constraints regarding cardinality are more difficult to model, much less enforce.

Which leads us to:

**IDs are not by themselves keys**

Everyone loves to slap auto-incrementing integers on tables and call them keys.  They are row pointers, nothing more.  Keys guarantee uniqueness of *data*, and `Ids` are not data, they are generated by the system.

For example, in your current data model it would be permissible to insert the exact same information into the `Product` table until I run out of integers.  There is no key.

**IDs can be keys, but only in addition to another key**

The primary key on `Product` in your example is most likely something along the lines of `(ProductCategory, ProductName, Color)`.  This is rather wide (in bytes), so it's reasonable to demote that key to an *alternate key* and make `ProductId`<sup>1</sup> the primary key of the table.

In this case, we say that `ProductId` is a surrogate for the original primary key.

**Limiting customers to 1 review per product**

Within the context of your problem, the primary key of `Review` is `(ProductId, CustomerId)`.  If we try to insert two reviews of the same `Product` authored by the same `Customer`, this will violate the primary key and the insert will fail.

As a benefit, we can abandon the useless `Id` column, which means we do not need an additional index to access a `Review` for a given `Product`<sup>2</sup>

**Other considerations**

1. `ProductCategory` should be it's own table and `Product` should have a foreign key constraint to that table to enforce consistency.
2. Right now an `Order` can only fulfill a single `Product`.  Usually this is implemented as `Order` followed by `OrderLine` (primary key `(OrderId, LineNbr)`) which would allow a `Product` to be sold at different prices (useful for sales/discounts).
3. I know it's just an example, but for the love of all that is sacred and holy, do not store the credit card information in the `Customer` table.  A `Customer` could have multiple payment methods, and in any case it's much safer to have that data encrypted and in a table with very limited access.

---

<sup>1</sup>A better key would be something like `ProductCd` which would reflect the manufacturer's part code, a barcode, or some internal signifier (internal to the business, not the database).

<sup>2</sup>You would still need an index on `CustomerId` in order to more quickly access the reviews of a particular `Customer`.